# How to handle code copy across seemingly unrelated questions/users?

Tags: discussion

I was in the review queue for *Triage* when I came across the question [CSS/HTML - Big White spaces when resizing browser between divs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30623404/3773066).

I thought, "*Hey... I edited that yesterday. How's it messy again?*"  Then I realized, no, I didn't edit this question; I edited this question: [Keep a div at the top of the screen after a certain number of pixels scrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30601808/3773066).

The newer question is worded in a way to claim the work his own and in comments states it is not a school project.  Small code bits being common among multiple code-bases is inevitable, but these two seem to derive from the same source and are too large to be coincidence. What's the appropriate action to take here? Even if that action is *nothing*.

Comment: There's a similar situation in this question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295937/duplicate-wrong-post - the consensus seemed to be because both questions were dupes of existing questions (and because it was likely homework) it didn't matter.  Seems really weird that this should be a thing that happens if it's not homework. Maybe they're co-workers?

Comment: High odds that the user was question-banned, he probably just created a new account today.  Flagging a moderator is best, they have ways to find out that it might be the same user.

Comment: It's the same guy farming out construction of his website one question at a  time.  His previous account is question banned, so he created a new one.  Flag him, point this out, and ask the mods to whup that ass.

Comment: No two people would use three non-breaking spaces when one could just use padding :)

Comment: @Will (technically @ all agreeing commentators) Out of interest, how do you know the previous account is question banned? As an assumption, it makes sense to me.  But how does one come to such a conclusion for a surety, if at all possible?

Comment: @OhBeWise - I'm guessing Will can see it because they've got over 20K rep and are a Trusted User.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few reasonable explanations for this:

1. Two developers working together on the same project.
2. New developers copy/pasting code they found on tutorials.
3. A user lost access to an account, or was question banned, and created a new account.

The only reason that really presents an issue is number 3, but a mod should be able to clear that up and merge/delete accounts if need be.

If it looks that suspicious to you, use a custom mod flag explaining exactly what you think the problem is and what you think needs to be done about it. Be clear and detailed.

Comment: It's definitely 3.